# How to join two tables and get the data

Tags: sql, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have the two tables as shown below.

Table #1: customer group table:

```
No    Reg                     Name 
----------------------------------------
111   Account Owner           Josh
111   Customer Group          Josh Group
```

Table #2: Customer table:

```
No    Name            Address
----------------------------------
111   Josh Ltd        Lala Land
```

How can I write a query that returns data like shown here:

```
No      Customer    Account_Owner  Customer_Group
--------------------------------------------------
111     Josh ltd    Josh           Josh Group
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select c.no, c.name as customer,
    max(case when cg.reg = 'Account Owner'  then name end) as account_owner,
    max(case when cg.reg = 'Customer Group' then name end) as customer_group
from customer c
inner join customer_group cg on cg.no = c.no
group by c.no, c.name
```

Comment: That's perfect many thanks its worked, before i had to add cg.reg as well in group by clause and its wasn't grouping them and after adding max it worked

Comment: Done, just for understanding how come adding max, group by does not ask to add cg.reg ?

Comment: @Sam: the `case` expression does the job. There is only (or: at most) one row in the group that match on each `case` condition, so you do get the `name` you want.